# PInvoke of self referential struct from C++

Tags: pinvoke

Following is a self referential struct from C++

```
typedef struct _FCV 
{
  unsigned long    ulID; 
  unsigned long    ulVersion; 
  unsigned long    ulStatus; 
  unsigned long    ulSize; 
  struct _FCV*     pNext; 
} FCV;
```

I need to use PInvoke to translate to C# struct,
What is the "pNext" i should declare?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have perhaps reached the point where p/invoke is not the best tool for the job. The complexity here may make a C++/CLI layer a more attractive option.

With p/invoke you'd need to declare the `pNext` field as `IntPtr`. Then you'd need to populate one instance of the struct for each item in the linked list. Finally you'd need to walk through the list assigning to `pNext`. That will require you to pin each struct with `GCHandle.Alloc` and then get the pinned address with `AddrOfPinnedObject`. Once the call has been made you then need to destroy all the `GCHandle` objects to un-pin the structs.

So it's possible to do, but the code may be rather unwieldy, and may not be particularly efficient. You should seriously consider C++/CLI instead.