# Import C++ function returning pointer of structs into VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, struct, dllimport

I have created a simple DLL in C++, for the sole purpose of isolating the issue and testing on a small scale the importing of a function that returns a list of structs with members of different types.

*dll_header.h*

```
#ifdef MY_DLL_EXPORTS
#define MY_DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

enum color_type
{
    RGB = 1,
    MONO = 2
};

struct my_struct
{
    unsigned char *name;
    char *value;
    color_type type;
    my_struct* next;
};

extern "C" struct my_struct MY_DLL_API * get_list(void);
```

*dll_header.cpp*

```
#include "dll_header.h"

MY_DLL_API my_struct * get_list(void)
{
    my_struct my_list[2];

    unsigned char name1[] = "name1";
    unsigned char name2[] = "name2";

    char val1[] = "val1";
    char val2[] = "val2";

    my_list[0].name = name1;
    my_list[0].value = val1;
    my_list[0].type = RGB;
    my_list[0].next = &my_list[1];

    my_list[0].name = name2;
    my_list[0].value  = val2;
    my_list[0].type = MONO;
    my_list[0].next = NULL;

    return my_list;
}
```

Like I said, I have to use these data types (cannot change them to strings or anything else because I am testing something and I need them like this)

Now, in my VB.NET application I import and try to retrieve the list like this from the DLL

*Form1.vb*

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Public Enum color_type
        RGB = 1
        COLOR = 2
    End Enum

    Private Structure my_struct
        Public name As Byte()
        Public value As Char()
        Public type As color_type
        Public next As IntPtr
    End Structure

    Private Declare Function get_list Lib "my_lib.dll" () As IntPtr

    Private my_list As List(Of my_struct)

    Private Sub get_list()
        Dim my_list_pointer As IntPtr = get_list()

        my_list = New List(Of my_struct)

        Dim my_item As my_struct

        While my_list_pointer <> IntPtr.Zero
            my_item = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(my_list_pointer, GetType(my_struct)), my_struct)

            my_list.Add(my_item)

            my_list_pointer = my_item.next
        End While
    End Sub
```

I have tried many other methods, specially changing data types but so far here I am, stuck with this exception when trying to run the code:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Trying to find a way to make these two understand each other

Comment: Why are you storing text in unsigned char arrays? What are you using 8 bit text? You talk about wide char but the example usage is for 8 bit text.

Comment: What I am doing is trying to emulate another library (of which I only have the DLL, not the source code) which uses the same unsigned char type to store a string that is later converted into wstring. That is why I cannot change it

Comment: You can choose whichever types work. Certainly feeding in 8 bit text isn't going to help

Comment: As far as I know, P/Invoke do not support recursivity as it as to know the whole structure size.

Comment: @phil the structure size is fixed. No recursion here with relation to size of structure.

Comment: Of course, before you try to call from vb you should make sure the c++ dll code is correct. It isn't. You return a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope when the function returns. And then you only assign to the first element of the array. There are many many problems here. Concentrate on your c++ code first.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So you are sure that P/Invoke allows to marshal a list (`next` pointer to other items). I have never seen that.

Comment: Sure it can be done. You use IntPtr and then Marshal.PtrToStructure. The problem with the question is that it has huge numbers of errors. Once they are ironed out the concept is perfectly viable using pinvoke without unsafe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan See my updated answer. In another similar question, you suggest to use C++/CLI for someone else that have a list... If OP want to avoid as much as possible modifying existing code, then most anomalies could be fixed in the extra mixed mode DLL.

Comment: @Phil I agree that mixed mode could make things easier. But you claim that this type is not consumable with pinvoke. And I am railing against that claim. It is false.

Comment: Well, I haven’t read the VB.NET code before my first answer... While it look possible to do it using IntPtr, you don’t get a managed list... so it is a compromise which might make the code harder to use if the list would be used a lot from VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Either use mixed mode C++ to do the translation between native and managed types or use types that are compatible with P/Invoke.

Looking how Win32 define structure (and function that use those) is a good start to help you understand how to define compatible structures as one of the main intent of P/Invoke is to be able to use Win32 API from managed code.

If you go for mixed mode, then you can do whatever required translation between both world as you can mix native C++ and C++/CLI in the same assembly. So essentially, you would write code that convert the native structure into a managed one and then VB.NET will be able to use that managed code (assuming that you use types available in VB.NET for example).

Well, if you go for the mixed mode route, you generally ends up with 3 DLLs/Assemblies/Executable as you would have the original C++ DLL (native code), the VB.NET code (managed) and the mixed mode C++ assembly in between.

**Update**

While it could be relatively easy to provide code if the list is read only, if this is not the case, it could be much harder depending how the code is expected to be used and what are the availaible function in the existing DLL.

The starting point would be to create a `ref class` in C++/CLI.

**Some similar questions**

https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/674468-passing-linked-list-c-dll-c-pinvoke

[Return list of points (x,y,z) from C to C# using PInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627592/return-list-of-points-x-y-z-from-c-to-c-sharp-using-pinvoke)

[PInvoke of self referential struct from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446799/pinvoke-of-self-referential-struct-from-c)

**Problem with your code**

Your exported function retuns a pointer to a local variable which is undefined behavior.

**Additional observation**

If your original list is an array, the why making it a list also? An array would be easier to marshal and use. And probably perform better too.

When defining you structure, you have be explicit on how strings are marshalled and the alignment that should be used. You shoull validate that everything is as expected.

Comment: If I could change the code of the DLL I would but I cannot. I have to keep those types because I am testing a scenario for another library (of which I only have the DLL, not the source). My only option is to adapt the VB.net code in order to understand the struct

Comment: As I said, with mixed mode C++ option, you add an extra layer in between and you can do whatever you want. If you want to use P/Invoke, then you have to ensure that your functions and structures are compatible with what P/Invoke support. It is as simple as that.

Comment: I see, so it's an in-between DLL which converts data from the first DLL into data easier to pass to the VB.net app. I guess that's an option, too

Comment: @phil This looks perfectly possible with pinvoke. You don't seem to have addressed the crux of the question at all. At best your answer should be a comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Possibly, if you use IntPtr... and unsafe code to handle your strings for example... Usually, you need to know the size of an object to marshall. Even if it was possible, it would be a pain to use. Also explain me how you would handle a list with P/Invoke... And if the list is not read-only, how would memory allocation be handled? If you think it is possible with P/Invoke, you can write an answer...

Comment: No need for unsafe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Suggesting to use mixed mode C++ is clearly an answer to the problem. And my answer is clearly more than a comment. Also, in a case like this one, it is hard to give any code if it is what you want as it is a lot of work...

Comment: Nope. Not an answer at all. Question can't really be answered in its current form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are contradicting yourself... Either it is possible to use P/Invoke with the structure as defined in the question in which case you could clearly give and answer or if it is not possible and OP does not want to modify existing DLL, then my answer would be clearly the way to do it.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to do this with pinvoke. The fact that I won't answer a question that should be closed doesn't mean that pinvoke can't be done here. You posted an answer and I voted and commented. I don't need to write an answer myself before I do that.